# How much power will 4 germicidal lamps use?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, electrical

I was wondering if this portable power supply will be sufficient for running 4 UVC lamps all at once. If so, for approximately how long?

Power Supply: [SUAOKI G100 27000mAh /3.7V Power Bank Station 100W AC, Type-C Quick Charge 3.0 USB, Solar Rechargeable Portable Power Generator for Travel Outdoor Use for MacBook Smartphone Camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07GFRDM5W)

UVC Lamps: [UV Linear Clean & Germicidal Lamp Kit for up to 100 sq. ft. Room with 5ft Cord and Plug (Ozone Free)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079SZ8NZR)

Answer (score 0):

Rough idea without any losses is 4 * 6 = 24 W

so 100Wh / 24W is just over 4 hours, but no other losses are considered and assumes the full capacity of 100Wh can be used which may not be the case... Also the stated 6W per lamp may not be fully accurate ie start up demand may be different.